# Wait for a device and serve response to a web page

Tags: javascript, node.js, nfc, pcsc

I'm trying to use nfc module from npm to read smartCard and send results to a web interface.

Everything goes well as far as my card reader is plugged in.
But if the card reader is not plugged in, the web server (nodejs) freezes and does not serves pages.

Here is my code in `utils.js`:

```js
exports.rfidPolling = function(socket){
        var nfc = new NFC()
        nfc.on('reader', reader => {                
                reader.autoProcessing = false;
                reader.aid = 'F222222222';
                notifyFn(socket,`${reader.reader.name}  device attached`)
                ...
        })
        nfc.on('error', err => {
                console.log('an error occurred', err);
                errorFn(socket,`An error occured : ${err}`)
        });

}
```

And in my file `server.js` I call `rfidPolling` function as follow :

```js
... 
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    utils.rfidPolling(socket)
})
...
```

I think the `nfc.on('reader',...` is the reason why it's freezing.

But I can't figure out a way to avoid this...

Thank you

Cheers

Comment: try enclosing it in  try block?

Comment: do you do `nfc.start()` ? Is your `notifyFn` the exit path? did you try to set breakpoints? my guess is your callbacks never get called due to not actually reading? - but it works when card is plugged in? weird ...

Answer (score 0):

## analysing the [source](https://github.com/camme/node-nfc)

---

> ```
> class NFC: public Nan::ObjectWrap {
>   public:
>     static NAN_METHOD(New);
>     static NAN_METHOD(Start);
>     static NAN_METHOD(Stop);
> ```

#### with [`nfc.Start`](https://github.com/camme/node-nfc/blob/34222fb4bda0fdfe3f4e365cb96f169335280e5e/src/nfc.cc#L383) handling:

> ```
> nfc_device *pnd;
> ...
> pnd = nfc_open(context, ...)
> ```
>
> [nfc_open](http://www.libnfc.org/api/group__dev.html#ga9a0b9811c0e7f93e7474db82a1fb4501)

and in case there is no device `pnd` will be `null` and thus triggers:

> ```
> if (pnd == NULL) {
>    nfc_exit(context);
>    return Nan::ThrowError("unable open NFC device");
> }
> ```

which [leads](http://inherits(nfc.NFC,%20events.EventEmitter);) in your example to:

> ```
> errorFn(socket,\`An error occured : ${err}\`)
> ```

### some idea to try:

```
exports.rfidPolling = function(socket){
        var nfc = new NFC()
        nfc.on('reader', reader => {                
                reader.autoProcessing = false;
                reader.aid = 'F222222222';
                notifyFn(socket,`${reader.reader.name}  device attached`)
                ...
        })
        nfc.on('error', err => {
                console.log('an error occurred', err);
                errorFn(socket,`An error occured : ${err}`)
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            nfc.Stop()
            notifyFn(socket,`${null} device timeout`)
        }, 4000)
        nfc.Start() // undefined | Error 
}
```